# comma separated data display in angular on the basis of condition

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular10

I am working on a angular application. I have a ngFor in my html code which is as follows.

```
<span *ngFor="let data of myData">
                <img  src="assets/myImage.png">
                <span>
                    {{data.title}}</span>,
            </span>
```

The problem is that myData array can have one single value or more than one value at run time. I want to have a display such that if one value is present then only one value is shown but if more that one value is present those should be separated by comma. In my above code I just put "," after span. It is working fine with more than one value but in case of single value comma still will be there. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can leverage `last` local variable of the `*ngFor` directive https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

```
<span *ngFor="let data of myData; last as isLast">
                <img  src="assets/myImage.png">
                <span>{{data.title}}</span>
                <ng-container *ngIf="!isLast">,</ng-container>
            </span>
```

Comment: How to give a little space after "," everytime. As if more elements are present "," and next element is displayed very close to each other

Comment: with css or `,&nbsp;`

Comment: you mean something liks this  <ng-container *ngIf="!isLast">,&nbsp;</ng-container>?

Comment: yeah, `&nbsp;` is escaped html for space symbol

Comment: your solution worked for me. Just a question. Is there is any way I can use div instead of span and get title comma separated?

Comment: there are many ways to do it with css. The simplest one is to set `display: inline-block` on the divs. BTW you can put that comma inside the span (or div) as well `<span>{{data.title}}<ng-container *ngIf="!isLast">,&nbsp;</ng-container></span>`